# Get video-urls from graph-api from a facebook-group-album

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i have a public facebook-group. in this group, i can get all albums with

`curl  https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/1262207083938400?fields={name,description,cover_photo,id}&access_token=XXX`
with this url, i get the base-information.

after that, i get all photos (the photo-ID) from that album by ID

> https://graph.facebook.com/1267946303364478/photos?fields=images&access_token=XXX

with this url, I can make "title", the "description ob album" and all the pictures of album.

now, I want to get the videos too! but how?

I can´t find some video-ID´s!?

Comment: Well probably not by asking for `/photos`, I guess. Was https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/group/videos to obvious?

Comment: /v3.2/1262207083938400/videos and /v3.2/1262207083938400?fields=videos does not work. but this is explainable: i always have albums ... images and videos mixed in the album. i think, the correct way is /v3.2/1267946303364478/???? <- thats the ID of the album / media.set, there is a field like "photos" but there is no field named "videos" :-(

Comment: The real post on FB you can see here: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=oa.1267946303364478&type=3

Answer (score 2):

I got the posted video URL in this way on version 6.0.

> me?fields=feed.limit(50){full_picture,**attachments{target,description,title,media}**,comments{from},shares,created_time,from,story,message}

The field **attachments** have the following properties

> target,description,title,media

the **media** contain a **source** key this included the video URL